# How to disable pop-up blocker on Safari on MacBook Air

Tags: macos, mac, safari

I regularly use Zoom links, and I want it so that I don't have to click allow every time I open the zoom link. Specifications: Safari 15.1, macOS Monterey, and have a MacBook Air M1 late 2021. I've tried going to safari preferences and allow popups, but I still have to click allow every time even after allowing popups.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Safari Settings > Websites
- Choose "Pop-up Windows" on the left side
- Select "Allow" for specific websites and/or "When visiting other websites"

Comment: I did that, but it's still not working for zoom. Every time I open a link, I am forced to click the `Allow` button

Comment: Could you show us the exact message/button in a screenshot?

Comment: @KevinGrabher They are referring to the alert that appears when you click Join Meeting, it's not a regular popup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable this prompt with Safari alone.

If you regularly join the same meeting code, you can create a link to it that goes directly to the Zoom application and bypasses Safari:

```
zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno=123456789&pwd=xxxx
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still forced to click the `Allow` button every time. It works in Firefox and Chrome... I think it is a Safari problem. I've switched to Firefox instead.

Comment: It will work if you don't use the zoommtg link in Safari. You can use that link in other applications (such as a file bookmark or a Notes entry)